# Issues with code for google-script (from drive to sheet)

Tags: google-apps-script

I am currently looking to get file names from google drive to my google sheet. I have around 30 files in my drive, and I want their file name to appear in my google sheets. All files are located in one folder.

I have tried to do this through script google, but something seems to be wrong as I get an error code. Below is the code I found through other sites but something goes wrong....

```
function list_all_files_inside_one_folder_without_subfolders(){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1HPv9-umg0XQ8Fa9UV8lDr6O2Y4kAIAJe'); // I change the folder ID  here 
  var list = [];
  list.push(['Name','ID','Size']);
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()){
    file = files.next();
    var row = []
    row.push(file.getName(),file.getId(),file.getSize())
    list.push(row);
  }
   sh.getRange(1,1,list.length,list[0].length).setValues(list);
}
```

Comment: please don't post code as an image, as said in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (which you should read).

Comment: Can you paste the code in your post? Also what is the exact error code that is displayed when you tried to run your script?

Comment: I will update the code in the question.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null (line 14, file "Code")

Comment: How do you run this function? Is it a from a script attached to a spreadsheet or a project based script ?

Comment: It is a project based script I run it as

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function list_all_files_inside_one_folder_without_subfolders(){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1HPv9-umg0XQ8Fa9UV8lDr6O2Y4kAIAJe'); 
  var list = [];
  list.push(['Name','ID','Size']);
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()){
    file = files.next();
    list.push([file.getName(),file.getId(),file.getSize()]);
  }
   sh.getRange(1,1,list.length,list[0].length).setValues(list);
}
```

Comment: Hey Cooper - I got this error message "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null (line 11, file "Code")". Maybe I need to structure my folder in a certain way?

Comment: The issue is that he is running the function from a project based script and therefore sheet `sh` can not be defined. Create a spreadsheet, go to tools script editor and run the script from there.

Comment: Refer to Marios's answer above. I just ran it again and it works from the script editor.

Comment: amazing, finally managed. Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: If you want to do this inside of a tree structure, try recursion.